# LINQ query where boolean value is true or false

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

How can I compare a boolean value to both true and false in a LINQ query?

If hideCompleted is true, I want to show values where IsCompleted is false
If hideCompleted is false, I want to show values where IsCompleted is true or false

Example:

```
(t1.IsCompleted ?? false == (hideCompleted == true ? false : (true || false)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to be sure I understand you correctly, if hideCompleted is false, you don't care what the value of IsCompleted is? If so...

```
!(hideCompleted && t1.IsCompleted)
```

Comment: While is answer is intuitive and logically correct, I encountered issues when using this with linq to entities. Max Zerbini's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Build your query based on `hideCompleted` being true, similar to this approach:

```
var query = dc.SomeTable;
if (hideCompleted)
{
    query = query.Where(t1 => !t1.IsCompleted);
}
```

This way when `hideCompleted` is true you filter for `t1.IsCompleted` being false. When `hideCompleted` is false your original query will grab all results regardless of the value of `t1.IsCompleted`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this condition

```
where (hideCompleted==true && t1.IsCompleted==false) || (hideCompleted==false)
```